# Can servers ever return headers not beginning with HTTP?

Tags: http, http-headers

When I checked URLs for headers, they always start with `HTTP`. For example, `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.

If I remember, I think in the past, headers started with `Status:` followed by a code.

Currently I run a website that always return headers beginning with `HTTP/1.1`.

Has there been a case at least within the last few years where headers do not begin with `HTTP`? If so, please enlighten me so I can update my apache module accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for any valid response over the HTTP protocol, the server must respond with an `HTTP/x.x` type header.

As I understand it, the `Status:` response header is something a CGI script would set for the web server to then generate a correct `HTTP/x.x` type header (thus overriding the default response).

More information in these StackOverflow questions:

- [Syntax of HTTP status headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009840/syntax-of-http-status-headers)
- [PHP: How to send HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code)